# Windows Server Manager crashing when promoting to domain controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2022

I have a problem when promoting my Windows Server 2022 to a domain controller.

So I installed the Active Directory Tools and then I wanted to promote the server to a domain controller. As soon as I want to create a new forest and click in the field to name it, the server manager crashed about 3 seconds later.
[Here is the field that I'm clicking in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRPcm.png)

I've tried to update and repair some .NET stuff and I even setup a whole new server.

Thanks for the help^^

Comment: You may want to try Reddit Homelab, however if Server Manager is crashing on a new server that is a red flag that something fundamental is broken.

Comment: Yea thats what I thought. The server is running on a proxmox platform. Maybe there's something up with that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What version of Windows Server 2022? I'm assuming you're following this https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Windows_2022_guest_best_practices .
Are you able to provide any logs? Do you get a memory dump? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/generate-a-kernel-or-complete-crash-dump

Answer (score 0):

Set your keyboard to US international layout.